# I do not understand some of the badges

Tags: discussion, badges

Specifically , the "good answer" and "great answer" two, it seems I have a few answers which would qualify.

[Keep the Ubuntu package version I'm using now](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86226/keep-the-ubuntu-package-version-im-using-now/86235#86235)

That answer has 5 upvotes.

It is not really a big deal, just trying to understand how the system works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you currently don't have any answer that would qualify for any of the badges. [The good answer badge](https://askubuntu.com/badges/24/good-answer) is given to answers with **25** upvotes. [The great answer badge](https://askubuntu.com/badges/25/great-answer) is given to answers with **100** upvotes. (Neither do you currently qualify for the [the nice answer badge](https://askubuntu.com/badges/23/nice-answer) which is given to answers with **10** upvotes.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, so it is upvotes The badges says "Answer score of 25 or more " , perhaps a clarification that "score" = "up votes" as when an answerer gets an upvote one gets reputation , thus is it not clear from the description what a "score" means

Comment: @bodhi: you want to take that up on "main" meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99007/why-is-there-no-badge-for-questions-with-upvotes